# Orders before 3pm: SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a order table with column orderdate (Timestamp)
I want to select all orders before 3PM. i am not expert in SQL.
I have tried like this,

```
select * from tableA where orderdate < '%Y-%M-%D 15:00:00.000'
```

Any help please

Comment: Is that column really of type `timestamp`? If so, you have other problems.

Comment: My fault...  the datatype of orderdate is "Datetime".

Comment: WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, orderdate) < ...

Comment: you might want to check if the orderdate is stored as UTC also, you may need to adjust your time.

Comment: What is the problem with what you posted? are you getting no rows back, or are you getting too many?  do you only want orders before 3pm for a particular day?

Answer (score 1):

you can convert into time and check whether it is < 3pm

```
SELECT * from yourtable where convert(time, orderdate) < '15:00:00.000'
```

Comment: Converting from datetime to time is one of those rare cases where a function with a column is actually SARGable. This is the best way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `substr` to get the hour part of the timestamp, providing you have a string representation in a known format.

If your format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, it would be `select * from wherever where substr(orderdate, 11,2) < 15`.

Comment: This will work but is nonSARGable so any indexing would be rendered useless.

Comment: @SeanLange Absolutely. I have a suspicion though that OP does not have an index setup in the first place) And in many databases (don't know about Microsoft) there isn't even a way to achieve what is requested while still hitting the index, short of making a functional index or a separate column.

Comment: Sure this can be a SARGable query. See the response from Kannan above. Converting from datetime to time is fully sargable. And of course we should never write a nonSARGable query and assume there is no index. And even if there isn't an index today, our query should be written in such a way as to enjoy the benefit of the index if one is created. :)

Answer (score -1):

> `select * from tableA where datepart(hour,cast(orderdate as date))`

Comment: This is nonSARGable and as posted it doesn't even work.